# How to write a biconditional negative statement in if-then form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a statement

> Either it's not Saturday or I have to go to work

that I want to write in if-then (conditional statement) form.

I know that

$-p V q ≡ p → q$

So I identified the propositions as such:

> p = it's not Saturday
>
> q= I have to go to work

and this would give me

> if it's not Saturday then I have to go to work

My confusion is this: the statement "It's not Saturday" is already negated in its ENGLISH form.

It is correct to say p = It's not Saturday or should it be -p = It's not Saturday?

I'm getting really confused between when the English statement is already negated.

Comment: Indeed it is unintuitive to represent denials with "positive" predicates.  It is not wrong to do so, but it can be a source of confusion.  The remedy is simple: if it is confusing you, then do not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, let $P$ = "It's Saturday".

Then, letting $Q$ = "I have to go to work", the given statement is 
$$\lnot P \lor Q$$
which is equivalent to 
$$P \rightarrow Q$$
or in words, "If it's Saturday, then I have to go to work".

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you might want to define -

$p ≡ $ It's sunday

$q ≡ $ I have to go to work

And then we'll have - $\lnot p \lor q ≡ p \rightarrow q$.

If it's sunday ($p ≡ T$) - $T \rightarrow Q ≡ T \iff Q ≡ T$

If it's not sunday ($p ≡ F$) - $F \rightarrow Q ≡ T$ ("I can do whatever i want")

If i have to go to work ($Q ≡ T$) - $p \rightarrow T ≡ T \iff p ≡ T$ (it's sunday)

If i don't have to go to work ($Q ≡ F$) - $p \rightarrow F ≡ T \iff p ≡ F$ (it's not sunday)

Comment: thank you. with the statement containing the word "Either" at the beginning would you say that makes in an exclusive OR?

Comment: More, it could be Monday, or Tuesday, or  ...